# Вопросы вместо китайских символов Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, символы, utf-8

*У меня проблемы с китайскими символами в Delphi 7*.
Прошу помочь мне с решением проблемы. Желательно с помощью
функции `WideCharToMultiByte` и типом `WideString`.

Answer (score 2):

Используй версию делфы, начиная с RAD 2009 =)